# override default new operator for an array of a class C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pinvoke, new-operator

I am using pinvokes to call native code.

if I want to create an array of the native objects I currently do the following

```
public class MyClass() {
    // allocate a single myClass;
    public MyClass() {
        _myClass = myclass_create();
        _length = 1;
    }
    public MyClass(int numArgs) {
        //pInvoke call to create an array of myclass;
        _myClass = myclass_array_create(UIntPtr);
        _length = numArgs;
     }

     //access the indexed element of myclass
     public MyClass this[int index] {
         get {
             MyClass ret = new MyClass();
             ret._myClass = myclass_array_element(this._myClass, (UIntPtr)index);
             return ret;
         }
     }

     public int Length {
         get {
             return _length;
         }
     }

     public void foo(){
         //lots of other code
     }


     [DllImport(DLL_IMPORT_TARGET)]
     private static extern IntPtr myclass_create();
     [DllImport(DLL_IMPORT_TARGET)]
     private static extern IntPtr myclass_array_create(UIntPtr numArgs);
     [DllImport(DLL_IMPORT_TARGET)]
     private static extern IntPtr myclass_array_element(IntPtr args, UIntPtr index);
     // ... more dllimports here ...

     //pointer to native object
     IntPtr _myClass;
     int _length;
}
```

This is now used as follows:

```
// Create an array of 15 MyClass objects
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(15);
for( int i = 0; i < myClass.Length; ++i) {
    //run foo on each object in the array
    myClass[i].foo()
}
```

I have this working just find however it is a little unusual to call new for something that is an array with out doing an array new.

is there a way that I can override the new operator for this class so the typical use of the new operator can be used instead?

I would like the code to look like this

```
// Create an array of 15 MyClass objects
MyClass[] myClass = new MyClass[15];
for( int i = 0; i < myClass.Length; ++i) {
    //run foo on each object in the array
    myClass[i].foo()
}
```

Is there a way to do this with my code?

Comment: You're not creating an array -- `MyClass` is not in and of itself an array.  You are simply treating it like one.  But the same is true for every collection class.  Neither can you accomplish what you want nor would it be a good idea (it would confuse readers of your code that it is an array when in fact it's not)

Comment: This code does not compile. Look at your indexer.

Comment: Do what exactly? Your library unless you have the source cannot be modified. myclass_array_create(UIntPtr) is simply returns the starting address of the array that is created. What you want to do and what you are doing is exactly the same.

Comment: @leppi I am not surprised it does not compile. I tried to take the relevant parts of already existing code that works and try and refactor it to make it understandable for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot in any way override the behavior of how an array is initialized.  You need to either:

1. Use a different type that wraps an array, as you showed in the question.
2. Call a method on the array after creating it to add additional initialization (i.e. assign a bunch of values to each index).
3. Create a new method that, when called, will create and then initialize the array.

Comment: I kind of had that assumption to start out with. I think the way it is done is probably the best solution.  I still asked, someone may have a solution I just could not find.